# Weird behaviour of \small{\date{}}

Tags: beamer, date

I wanted to get beamer to show the date in a smaller font and mistakenly wrapped the `\date{December 15, 2017}` field with the `\small` tag. Surprisingly, instead of emitting an error or changing the font size, pdflatex produced ‘December **11**, 2017’ as a result. Is there an explanation for such behaviour?

**UPD**: It was pointed out that `\small` is a switch and does not take argument. However, `{\small \date{December 15, 2017}}` produces December **12**, 2017.

Comment: Welcome to this site. You should post a full Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: I am not sure what you did but perhaps you should try `\date{\small{}December 15, 2017}` instead of `\date{December 15, 2017}` as `\small` is a switch .

Comment: `\date{\small{XXX}}` works as expected. `\small{\date{XXX}}` produces the weird result.

Comment: Henri's warning in his answer is correct. From your comment I am not sure whether you understand the difference of `\small{foo} bar` and `{\small{}foo} bar`.  `\small` is a switch and does not take an argument.

Comment: @CampanIgnis, thanks for the hint. `{\small \date{December 15, 2017}}` incredibly produces `December 12, 2017`.

Comment: You are switching size before you store a string (date) which is output later. Place the switch inside.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example of code that produces the wrong date. Otherwise, it’s rather difficult to give sensible help about the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\small` has nothing to do with the problem.

The fact is that `\date` does *not* print the date, but rather sets an internal variable to the date given as argument. The working is essentially

```
\newcommand{\date}[1]{\renewcommand{\internaldate}{#1}}
```

(different names and more complex action, but this is the idea) and the code for `\maketitle` will use `\internaldate`.

When you do

```
\small{\date{July 38, 1973}}
```

or

```
{\small\date{July 38, 1973}}
```

the `\date` instruction is performed in a group, so the redefinition of `\internaldate` is forgotten as soon as the group ends and you eventually get today’s date, which is used by default. This explains why you got **11** when you posed the question and **12** when you revised it. In the first case the group is because `\small` takes no argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realised today that it has smth to do with extracting the current date, but did not grasp the whole picture.

Answer (score 5):

Don't put `\small` in the `\date{...}`.  This will have unforeseen side effects.  Better change the way the date is printed using `\setbeamerfont`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the point was to explain the strange behaviour, not how to change font size.

Comment: @gigabytes “Strange input might yield strange output.”  Is that enough explanation?  Also I can't even reproduce the problem in the question, can you?